# Why does this Ruby 'if' not behave as expected?

Tags: ruby

Im sure I am missing something here but none the less.

```
foo['bar'] = nil

if(foo['bar'] == nil)
   puts "foo bar is nil :("
```

However, nothing happens? Any thoughts?

Comment: The problem was with ruby itself (wont go into details), but marked as answered as there where some very good responses.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need an `end` statement to close your `if` i.e.

```
if(foo['bar'] == nil)
   puts "foo bar is nil :("
end
```

Note that there is a `nil?` method for checking if something is `nil` and the brackets around your condition aren't necessary so it would be more idiomatic Ruby to write:

```
if foo['bar'].nil?
  puts "foo bar is nil :("
end
```

As [Arkku](https://stackoverflow.com/users/204883/arkku) commented, a single line `if` can be written concisely as:

```
puts "foo bar is nil :(" if foo['bar'].nil?
```

Which is better depends on the context (e.g. do you want to emphasise the condition or emphasise what happens if the condition is true) and a certain amount of personal preference. But as an example you might put a guard condition at the start of a method e.g.

```
raise "bar needed" if foo['bar'].nil?
```

Comment: +1, but as an additional note, in Ruby the one-line `if`, which the asker might have wanted for brevity, can be written `puts 'nil' if foo['bar'].nil?`

Comment: @Arkku Yep, I will update the answer to include this for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

nil is treat it exactly like false in a condition. So you don't need test if your variable is really nil.

```
foo = {}
foo['bar'] = nil
puts "foo bar is nil :(" unless foo['bar']
puts "foo bar is nil :(" if !foo['bar']
```

In ruby just nil and false return false in condition statement.

Comment: Of course, it may sometimes be desirable to differentiate between nil and false, e.g. here the printed message would be incorrect for false, claiming that it was nil.

Comment: "nil == false" is misleading because they are not equal. Ruby treats nil as a false conditional test result.

Answer (score 1):

```
irb(main):002:0> foo = {}
=> {}
irb(main):003:0> foo['bar'] = nil
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> foo['bar']
=> nil
irb(main):005:0> if foo['bar'] == nil
irb(main):006:1> puts "foo bar nil"
irb(main):007:1> end
foo bar nil
=> nil
```